# Routing to a different page in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a link where I click the register button and it goes onto the register.html, without it needing for the page to start reloading. But when I click the register link, nothing seems to happen when I click it.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Login">

<label for="login">Login</label>
<input id="login" ng-model="login" type="text">
<br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" ng-model="password" type="text">
<br>
<button type="button" ng-click="login()">Login</button>


<a  href="#!register" >Register</a>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/",{
            templateUrl:"index.html",
        })
        .when("/register",{
            templateUrl:"register.html",
            controller:"Registration"
        });
})
app.controller('Login',['$scope', function ($scope) {

}])

app.controller("Registration", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "I love London";
});
```

register.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <h1>Registration page</h1>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Registration">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your link to:

```
<a href="register">Register</a>
```

Check documentation for details [$route#examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples)